# Meteor, updated app and now `TypeError: check is not a function`

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, updates

I am working on updating an old meteor project. It was on a very old version, older than `1.0.0`. This app is experiencing this problem at Meteor `1.4.2.3`. Another app is working just fine at the same version.

I've made many changes to get it to build without any errors, and it began to crash at startup with this message:

```
TypeError: check is not a function
    at convertRegexpToMongoSelector (packages/mongo/collection.js:412:3)
    at packages/mongo/collection.js:389:18
    at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:155:22)
    at Function.Mongo.Collection._rewriteSelector (packages/mongo/collection.js:386:5)
    at new CursorDescription (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:877:36)
    at OplogHandle._startTailing (packages/mongo/oplog_tailing.js:236:29)
    at new OplogHandle (packages/mongo/oplog_tailing.js:76:8)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:222:25)
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
```

I of course tried simply adding the `check` package: `meteor add check`.
I even tried removing it and adding it again just to be sure. My `.meteor/versions` file contains this line: `check@1.2.4`

Before all of this, the app told me that my instance of [mongodb was using the old mmapv1 engine](https://guide.meteor.com/1.4-migration.html#update-from-mongo-2_4) and to update to the Wired Tiger one. It recommended doing this simply with a `meteor reset`, which I did and the message went away. I thought it might be relevant since the problem is clearly coming from inside `mongo`.

#### A New App Entirely

I decided to simply create a new app with a fresh `package.json` and everything, and re-add all of the packages it needed. I then copied over the relevant code from my app. I did this, and it began giving this different error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.shell-server.shell-server.js (packages/shell-server/shell-server.js:403:26)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:189:9)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:114:16)
    at Module.Mp.import (/home/blaine/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.7.7.xi5f9m++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime.js:70:16)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.shell-server.main.js (packages/shell-server/main.js:1:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:189:9)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:114:16)
    at /home/blaine/Business/PianoStudio/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/shell-server.js:563:15
    at /home/blaine/Business/PianoStudio/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/shell-server.js:569:3
    at /home/blaine/Business/PianoStudio/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:295:34
```

This is once again coming from meteor released packages.

I removed the `shell-server` package and that message went away, but the `TypeError: check is not a function` returned.

I tried to remove and add the `mongo` package. No effect.

I tried to rebuild the app by deleting the `.meteor` directory and re-creating it with `meteor create .` No effect.

I went through and commented out every single file containing server-side code (everything not in the `client` directory), since it's crashing on the server and clearly not a client-side issue. No effect.

Finally I tried to downgrade my project slightly, to `1.4.1.1`. No effect.

Here's my new `package.json` in case that's relevant:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.18.0"
  }
}
```

**What could be hiding in my app to cause something like this?** The error message is completely unhelpful,

Comment: have you already tried deleting your `~/.meteor` directory? Rebuilding the packages (trigger by that) might help.

Comment: Just tried it. Deleted the directory and ran `meteor create .` No effect.

Comment: `meteor create`? That shouldn't be necessary. Are you sure you deleted `~/.meteor` and not `.meteor` (in your project folder)?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you were referring to my home directory! I tried that and it worked :) Post an answer giving that advice and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `check` package inside your `.meteor/packages` file.

Comment: I think you should check the value/type of `check` function to make sure is is not overridden, a simple `console.log` should be enough. Also you should include the content of .meteor/packages in the question